# Ellipse equation on some plane

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, vector-analysis

In $\mathbb{R}^2$, we can write ellipse formula
$$\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1.$$
Or we can see $\mathbb{R}^2$ as a plane through $(0,0,0)$ and  $z = (0,0,1)$ as a normal vector.

Given $x = (1,0,0)$ dan $y = (0,1,0), \in \mathbb{R}^3$. There is a plane through $(0,0,0)$ and $(x+y)$ as a normal vector.

So that the equation of the plane is
$$x + y = 0$$

I want to find equation of ellipse on that plane. I have tried several ways, like substitution and etc but I can't find the equation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have the normal to the plane of the ellipse as $n = (1, 1, 0) $.  You need to specify where the major axis and minor axis are pointing.  Suppose $v_1, v_2$ are unit vectors, such

$ v_1 \cdot n = 0 , v_2 \cdot n = 0 , v_1 \cdot v_2 = 0 $

And suppose $a, b$ are the semi-major and semi-minor axes lengths, then the (parametric) equation of the ellipse is

$ p(t) = a \cos(t) v_1 + b \sin(t) v_2 $